# How can I assign `Request.QueryString["access_token"]` to `string a`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

When I check with breakpoint I see that `Request.QueryString["access_token"]` is not null.
But I can't assign it to string.
How can I do this ?

So  `string a = Request.QueryString["access_token"]`

Comment: Do exactly that, what's the issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors? If yes, what?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't assign it to string"? From its name, `QueryString` is actually a `string` and of course you can assign a `string` to a `string` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this --> `string a = Request.QueryString["access_token"].ToString();`

Comment: The `ToString()` is redundant, `QueryString` is a `NameValueCollection` who's indexer returns a string, see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx